# Error in automating binarizer of stanford parser (Python)

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford Parser to generate trees from the given data in the required annotated format. I am able to do it for a single file by running:

```
./lexparser.sh input_file > output_file
```

from the `stanford-parser-full-2018-02-27` folder. But, I have multiple files so I tried to automate it using python as follows :

```
import os
import glob
import subprocess

for movie in glob.glob("../full_movies/annotated/*.txt"):
    tree = subprocess.call(['./lexparser.sh', os.path.basename(movie)])
    with open("../full_movies/trees/" + os.path.basename(movie), "w") as fid:
        fid.write(tree)
```

But it shows the following error :

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
>   Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "movie_name.txt" as class path, filename or URL
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(IOUtils.java:1316)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.BuildBinarizedDataset.main(BuildBinarizedDataset.java:171)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "movie_name.txt" as class path, filename or URL
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromString(IOUtils.java:637)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.slurpFile(IOUtils.java:1159)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.slurpFile(IOUtils.java:1184)
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(IOUtils.java:1314)
>       ... 1 more

I am unable to understand this. Is it a mistake in my python script or something else is wrong here?
If you want to see the contents of `./lexparser.sh` let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide the contents of the script as well as the format of the stanford parser (is it a jar? or a maven project etc?) Since the error is in Java, it seems that you are not passing the correct format of the file to the parser.

Comment: Once you add that, try adding a java tag since it might get attention faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is simple you just give Filenames to the lex parser, because you call basename on it. But since lexparser isn’t in the same directory as the files you need to give the full path to the files. Just use movie and delete the os.path.basename call.